Running selenium or appium tests through browsermob proxy to capture network data with PAC system proxy settings
I am using hybrid automation framework using selenium/appium/rest assured etc, where we follow below steps:
launch the chrome browser -> listen to network calls -> get a particular field value from a response -> pass it on to get the otp from internal api -> proceed with further steps.
I am able to achieve (listen to network calls) using:
((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools() -> then some additional statements to read the response body of network calls -> proceed with next steps
If i want to achieve the above steps with mobile, instead of Chrome devtools, I have to use another proxy tool BrowserMobProxy in java. This creates a proxy server and we set this proxy to selenium or appium in chromeOption.setProxy(). And all the network calls will go through this and we can capture the request and response data.
I am on a corporate proxy which uses a PAC file hosted on a url(http://.com/.pac) to handle system proxy settings.
Normally when i run my tests on browser it by default takes system proxy settings and runs fine.
Has anyone come across any of the steps or know the solution? Please Help.
Thanks in advance.
When i configured BrowserMobProxy, that means all the default proxy settings will be overridden by BrowserMobProxy settings. And BrowserMob does not handle that PAC file proxy. When i run my tests the network calls to host which inside the network are passing and other calls outside the network are failing due to err_tunnel_connection_failed(Bad Host or cannot be resolved) since the proxy is changed to Manual(BrowserMob proxy).
My major requirement is:

Create a secondary proxy proxy1 - which handles requests coming from BrowserMobProxy based on the logic of the PAC file content

Create BrowserMobProxy proxy - which is then set to upstream to proxy1 with proxy.SetChainedProxy(proxy1.host, proxy1.port)

Configure my Selenium or Appium tests to run through BrowserMob proxy


By doing this I will be able to capture network data as well as the network calls will be resolved based on PAC file proxy.
